# Can we modify one component of a link and keep the others unchanged

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose a link diagram consists of two components $K_1$ and $K_2$. Suppose $K_1$ has some self crossings as well as some crossings with the other component $K_2$. If $K_1$ is isotopic to the trivial knot (unknot), my question is can we transform $K_1$ to the trivial knot by applying Reidemeister moves to the self crossings only and keep the crossings with $K_2$ unchanged? In general, can we just modify one component and keep the other unchanged.

Comment: If $K_1$ is the trivial knot, then what does it mean to transform it into the trivial knot? Do you want to perform Reidemeister moves on $K_1$ self-crossings only until $K_1$ has no more self-crossings?

Answer (score 2):

If I interpreted your question correctly, then no, it is not possible. The following link is called the [Whitehead link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link).

[image]

Let's say that the orange component is $K_1$ and the blue component is $K_2$. The component $K_1$ has one self-crossing, the component $K_2$ has no self-crossings, and there are four crossings between $K_1$ and $K_2$.

If we were able to "untie" $K_1$ by performing Reidemeister moves only involving self-crossings of $K_1$, then the resulting link would only have four crossings: $0$ self-crossings of any kind and $4$ crossings between $K_1$ and $K_2$. The Whitehead link is alternating (just look at the picture), and [Tait's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait_conjectures#Crossing_number_of_alternating_knots) (proven by Kauffman, Murasugi, and Thistlethwaite) states that any reduced alternating diagram minimizes crossing number. Thus there are no diagrams of the Whitehead link with fewer than 5 crossings.

Comment: I mean apply Reidemeister moves to only self crossings of $K_1$ to untie it. So the Whitehead link is a counterexample. I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: I see that the Whitehead link has non-trivial coloring. What if the link admit only trivial coloring for any coloring by a qaundle. Is there also a counterexample in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about quandle colorings of links. Maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: I mean is it also true if the link is unlink, in other words $K_1$ and $K_2$ can be splitted and each is an unknot.